# In Modeh Ani we thank Hashem for our neshama's return. Where do neshamas go?

Tags: death, sleep, tefilla

In Modeh Ani we thank Hashem for returning our Neshomos when we arise. Where do they go during our sleep? Do they go to the same place as the neshomos of the deceased?

Answer (score 3):

The *S'fas Emes* certainly seems to think the *n'shama* spends the night in the same *olam han'shamos* that it came from when the person was born. This is implied in the fact that in discussing *Modeh Ani*, he quotes the *g'mara* ([*Nida* 30b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=30b&format=pdf)) that describes the heavens sending down the *n'shama* and adjuring it to be righteous and follow *mitzvos* before its birth into the world.

> משביעין אותו תהי צדיק ואל תהי רשע

Comment: do you have a source or link to the S'fas Emes?

Answer (score 1):

No. People lose their capacity for free will and action while asleep, and get it back in the morning.

Comment: This might be what Rav Kook is saying in his commentary on _Modeh Ani_ in _Olas R'iya_ but I am not confident in my understanding of it to put it in an answer.

Comment: but we don't thank Hashem for returning our free will, we are thanking Him for returning our neshama... so that doesn't really answer my question...

Comment: How does this answer the question?